# I cannot get wifi with my toshiba satellite c55-a

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek, toshiba

I am very new to computing and I wanted to use linux and figured Ubuntu is a good place to start learning.

On installation I was able to see the option in my network manager that would give an option for mobile networks but that is not wifi and then many of the options disappears after a couple of days.  I have tried so many of the of the "solutions" that are on here but none of them has had an effect and this may be due to my lack of basic understanding of the OS.

```
    chickenbone@CBmindscape:~/Desktop/backports-3.11-rc3-1$ sudo modprobe -r rtl8188ee && sudo modprobe rtl8188ee
    FATAL: Error inserting rtl8188ee (/lib/modules/3.8.0-34-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

I had begun experimenting with many things like this and have a feeling that I may be just doing too much and the overlap of random garbage may be a problem.  this is the most recent code in a long line of attempts found on this board.

I got

```
rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013
```

from realteks website and tried to install this as well and it was not working.  I could not find an inf file in windows wireless drivers to add so thats no good.

What is going on here?  I have been at this for about 5 days now and would like this mess solved. there are no additional drivers to enable.  I lack many basic computing skills so please treat me with kid gloves, I need to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's re-run the backports install and see if we can find out what went wrong. Please open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.11-rc3-1
make clean
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Assuming every step goes without error, reboot and confirm the version of the driver:

```
modinfo rtl8188ee
```

Under 'version,' it ought to report that it is from backports-3.11-whatever. Next, see if it loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

If not, load it and see if there is an error message:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8188ee
```

Check for error messages here:

```
dmesg | grep rtl
```

If you have lengthy errors or warnings to show us, paste them here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: This has solved the problem.  Thank you very very much.